# Custom scrollspy jquery only works when handcoded

Tags: jquery, scrollspy

I've been stuck with this for a while now. I'm trying to make my own scrollspy. Thing is that it only works when handcoded, and if I try to do it through variables it keeps giving me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(check, 100);
});

function isScrolledIntoView()
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var year = $('.year').eq(2).attr("class");
    var test = year.split(' ');
    test = test[1];
    var elemTop = $(".item."+test).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(".item."+test).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var check = function(){
    var itemslength = $('.year').length;
    for (var i = itemslength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var year = $('.year').eq(i).attr("class");
        var yearsplitted = year.split(' ');
        if(isScrolledIntoView())
        {
            $(".year.2016").addClass("item-active");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".year.2016").removeClass("item-active");
        }
    }
};
```

You can see at the first function

```
var elemTop = $(".item."+test).offset().top;
```

If I try do that through variables, it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/DFh7z/68/

Edit: I used the wrong loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, only variable declarations are hoisted, not initializations. Consequently, when you call "setInterval" in your document.ready function, the "check" function variable will be undefined.

If you want to use a variable for your "check" function, try moving your set interval call to the end of your script like so:

```
function isScrolledIntoView()
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var year = $('.year').eq(2).attr("class");
    var test = year.split(' ');
    test = test[1];
    var elemTop = $(".item."+test).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(".item."+test).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var check = function(){
    var itemslength = $('.year').length;
    for (var i = itemslength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var year = $('.year').eq(i).attr("class");
        var yearsplitted = year.split(' ');
        if(isScrolledIntoView())
        {
            $(".year.2016").addClass("item-active");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".year.2016").removeClass("item-active");
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(check, 100);
});
```

This should get your script firing, but I suspect you'll need a bit more work to have your scroll spy extension fully functional.

Comment: Not quite working, this is what I'm trying to do: [http://jsfiddle.net/DFh7z/70/](http://jsfiddle.net/DFh7z/70/) I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`